# How do I delete extraneous deployment target settings from a build target

Tags: xcode, deployment-target

I have multiple build targets in my project. Some have tvOS set as the Base SDK whereas others have iOS set for this build setting. For some reason, despite only having one Base SDK set per build target, there are some that have multiple of the 'OS X Deployment Target' properties set.

Deployment targets shown in Xcode:

```
iOS Deployment Target       iOS 8.0
macOS Deployment Target     
tvOS Deployment Target      tvOS 9.2
watchOS Deployment Target
```

There is no blank option when I click on the dropdowns of versions next to the deployment target settings. Is there any way to remove one of these?

Comment: I'm in the same spot you're in. You might try manually editing the project.pbxproj file and deleting the lines containing MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET